# PayPal Integrtaion in Iphone5

Tags: ios6, payment-gateway, iphone-5, xcode4.6

I am working on Restaurant Application in iPhone using PayPal payment gateway for purchase of particular menu item. Will Apple approve this Restaurant Application? 
anybody suggest some guidelines to tackle this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about Apple policies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, apple will approve it. [App Store Review Guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/appstore/resources/approval/guidelines.html#purchasing-currencies)